# Open Browser with a specific url on sending request on API (.Net core MVC)

Tags: .net-core, request, itext, asp.net-core-webapi, response-headers

Working on .Net Core MVC and IText7, I'm filling a Pdf form (empty form PDF is already saved on server). What I want is, Whenever I send request to the link (can be a API endpoint), it should forces my browser to open the pdf on it. Opening the Pdf is already achieved by the writing the header of the response with pdf file and also the write content-disposition to the header but the main problem is:
How I can force my browser to be opened on sending a request to the .Net Core Application or .Net Core API?

Comment: Why not just use window.open() with api endpoint?

Comment: window.open() is also not working.